# LINUX: Using cat to remove columns in CSV - some have commas in the data

Tags: linux, csv, cat

I need to remove some columns from a CSV. Easy. 
The problem is I have two columns with full text that actually has commas in them as a part of the data. My cols are enclosed with quotes and the cat is counting the commas in the text as columns. How can I do this so the commas enclosed with quotes are ignored?

example:

```
"first", "last", "dob", "some long sentence, it has commas in it,", "some data", "foo"
```

i want to print only rows 1-4, 6

Comment: Please give some example input and your expect output.

Comment: Just exactly how are you doing this with `cat`? AFAIK `cat` has no editing capabilities. This looks like a job for `sed`.

Comment: @mikew As much as I love sed, this is a job for a csv parser.

Comment: @kevin Each to their own. Either way, it can't be done with `cat` alone.

Answer (score 2):

You will save yourself a lot of aggravation by writing a short Perl script that uses `Parse::CSV` http://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::CSV

I am sure there is a Python way of doing this too.

Comment: You can also use Text::CSV and Text::CSV_XS.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file | sed -e 's|^"||;s|"$||' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[\"], ?[\"]"}{print $2}'
```

Example:
http://ideone.com/g2gZmx

How it works:
Look at line:

```
"a,b","c,d","e,f"
```

We know that each row is surrounded by `""`. So we can split this line by `","`:

```
cat file | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[\"], ?[\"]"}{print $2}'
```

and rows will be:

```
"a,b   c,d   e,f"
```

But we have annoying `"` in the start and end of line. So we remove it with `sed`:

```
cat file | sed -e 's|^"||;s|"$||' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[\"], ?[\"]"}{print $2}'
```

And rows will be

```
a,b   c,d   e,f
```

Then we can simply take second row by `awk '{print $2}`.

Read about regexp field splitting in awk: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Field-Splitting.html

Comment: Great post! The `cat file` is not necessary.  One could do `sed -e'|^"||;s|"$||' file ... `

Comment: not really, sometime cvs has format as `1997,Ford,E350,"Super, luxurious truck"`, refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values